# Must the AppStore images be updated with 4'' screen size screenshots?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm in the process of bug-fixing an old application, that was released back in early 2012 with no 4'' screen size support.

According to modern AppStore review guidelines, **all** apps should be updated to support new screen size, and apps will be rejected for not doing so.

So I included 4'' launch image, added appropriate constraints and all works well.

But what about the screenshots on AppStore? Is updating them to 4'' version still a recommendation, or requirement already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **Yes**.

It is a requirement to upload screenshots for 4" iPhone screen sizes as well as retina images.

Comment: Thanks! Do you remember in what document Apple clearly states that requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure which of the many documents state that it is a requirement but it is most definitely in one of them. It is definitely outlined in iTunes Connect however when uploading screenshots before submitting your app. It could perhaps be defined in this one: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/2_BeforeYouBegin/BeforeYouBegin.html

Comment: You won't be able to submit the app without uploading at least one screenshot for each supported screen.